# Can I write, "The two best things about the party was the food and the music?"

Tags: verb-agreement

> The two best things about the party **was** the food and the music.

Is the statement right or not?
If it is not right then what is the right statement?
I am not clear about if we are using plural noun "things" and using single form of verb "was"  and the single noun in the next sentence.
With which plural in first part of sentence is used with single form of verb in the second. Is there any general rule?

Comment: _Two things_ are plural, so you need a plural verb.

Comment: That was the question i have asked. Then how is it off topic

Comment: It was off-topic because you simply asked "Is this right?" which is proof-reading. Now that your real question has been stated, it's no longer proof-reading, but it's not suited to ELU.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the plural form of the verb "The two best things were..."

The singular "...was..." would be understood, but would usually be considered to be an error.

In an inconsistent sentence like "The best thing about the party (...) the food and the music", you might find both "was" and "were". But now the meaning of the sentence is broken.